# Delete Datebase that duplicate between row

Tags: php, mysql, database, delete-row

If in database has

```
First     Last     distance
1          4          0.2         //line 1
2          6          0.5         //line 2
3          7          0.3         //line 3
4          1          0.2         //line 4
```

If I want delete line 4 because the result is equal line 1, How to write the code?

Comment: Do you want to just delete line 4, or are you trying to come up with something that will work in a general sense?

Comment: Please also explain what the columns mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidenote: Posted as a community wiki. I don't want rep from this.

This is basic MySQL using DELETE with a WHERE clause.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE col_x = 'y'
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

As per the manual:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Comment: Thank you, It's very helpful. I just start for learning about mysql.

Comment: @SafeRollins you can mark the question as solved though ;-)

Comment: OK, Thank for your advise.